# Can someone clarify whether this can be said as a proof?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

[image]

A person claims this to be a demonstration and not a proof my question is ,does it fit the bill of being a valid Mathematical proof?

Comment: Difference $10^{-n}$ already assumes that the value is $1$. It is obvious that $0.999\cdots $ cannot be larger than $1$, to refute that it is smaller than $1$ just argue that we surpass every real number smaller than $1$ with a sufficient number of nines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree with the statement that “This, however, is **not** possible as $n$ is **unbounded** above.” However, in order to prove that, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $10^{-n}<\varepsilon$, you can use the Archimedian property: there is some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>\frac1\varepsilon$ and therefore$$10^{-n}=\frac1{10^n}<\frac1n<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: can this be counted as a proof albeit a wrong one?

Comment: The question was: “does it fit the bill of being a valid Mathematical proof?” My answer is negative.